# How do I ensure that my blog posts show up on Google's Now Feed?

Tags: android, wordpress, blogs, feed, google-now

Even though we get a lot of traffic to our blog posts on our website, we never see them posted on the Google NOW Feed on Android devices. I realize that Google customizes this feed to each users past behavior. I do visit our website very frequently, but have never seen our blogs on this feed. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the fact that this is a site for programming questions, and this is not a programming question.

Comment: Programmatic solutions would be fine too.